# CSS Fluid layout trouble with a slot machine

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to create a simple slot machine. First of all I have a random background image on the body,and then I have a div with the slot machine itself. Inside the div with the slot machine there is a wrapper div which holds 3 divs each one having a background image with the slot numbers. The image has about 2000px height and background repeat on Y to create the impression that the slots are spinning infinitely.  The wrapper div I am using to hide the overflow but when I am trying to make the slots fluid I have some trouble aligning the wrapper div with the numbers with the slot machine itself.
Hope you guys understand what I am trying to do . I will share the code and two screenshots. Also I can upload the images if needed.

[image: asd]
[image: asd]

Tried playing a bit with the width of the wrapper but couldn't get where I wanted.

```
    <body>
      <div class="slot-machine">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="slot-strip"></div>
          <div class="slot-strip"></div>
          <div class="slot-strip"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>

    * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      border:0 none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html,body {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }

    body {
      background:url("bg.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      padding:300px 0;
    }

    .slot-machine {
      background:url("slot-machine.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
      margin:auto;
      width:1200px;
      height: 240px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .wrapper {
      float:left;
      width:330px;
      height:120px;
      margin-left:440px;
      margin-top:75px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    .slot-strip {
      background:url("slot-strip.png");
      width:110px;
      height:2000px;
      background-size: contain;
      float:left;
      background-position: 0 110px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
      .slot-machine {
        width:98%;
        background-size: contain;
      }

     .wrapper {
     }

    }
```

The slot machine and the slot numbers should decrease in size together.

Comment: can you provide code in form of pen or fiddle ?

Comment: `.wrapper margin-left: 440px` this seems a problem

Comment: @NishargShah sure , I will do it now.

Comment: You might want to consider percentage-based units of measurement to allow for responsiveness. As above, `margin-left:440px;` will not work very well cross-device.

Comment: @MatthewPage I used margin-left on the wrapper to move it on top of the slot machine. Didn't know how to do it properly

Comment: @ObsidianAge should I start from PC with percentage-based units or when I'm starting to use the media queries ? The background images in the div's look awful when I am starting to use them from the PC resolution.

Comment: @NishargShah here it is. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdMRGv thank you

Comment: i think your pen havn't images ?

Comment: @NishargShah weird, I can see them in the pen lol

Comment: i can't see anything expect one gray block

Comment: Don't know why it's showing it like that . I will give you the images links or tell me how can I help you to see them :D https://i.imgur.com/vsAw2o5.png  https://i.imgur.com/aiQraEj.jpg    https://i.imgur.com/X3hsGAX.png

Comment: ok, let me handle it wait for while

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187524/discussion-between-clauu-and-nisharg-shah).